# Django logs print statemeents are not writing to file

Tags: django

In django i am adding logging and storing logs to file. It is writing to files the infor and errors
But not print statements.

No print statements are coming.

I wants to write all including print statements also.

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
            },
            'simple': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'simple'
            },
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': 'logs.log',
                'formatter': 'simple'
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

Please have a look, how i can achive this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a proper logging system, you should change all the `print` to `logger.info` to log your statements.

Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#making-logging-calls).

Comment: I want to log print statements output to file without changing print to logger.info, can I do this?

Comment: @praveenchaudhary To do that, you could just wrap the `print` function to `logger.info`, by doing `print=logger.info`.